# Add text to beginning and end of a line in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file with over 5000 lines. I need to add the following characters before and after the string, JAMES, for example:

```
 '[^-_.*]JAMES[@-\.]'
```

Is this correct if I am trying to say that JAMES can be in the beginning of a line, or have dashes, underscores, any character 0 or more times before JAMES, and the @, dash, or period can be followed by JAMES?

I am using a list as a whitelist to print the emails that have a certain string (e.g. JAMES) to another file. So, it should take:

```
 cat file.txt | egrep -e -i < whitelist | sort -u > newfile.txt
```

file.txt has email addresses separated by new line.

So far, I used the following command in vim:

```
 '%s/^$/[^-_.*]'
```

However, all this did was add `[^-_.*]` to the end of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
:g/.*/s//^[-_.]*&[-@.]*/
```

The `.*` looks for the whole line, and the `:g/.*/` looks for that on every line in the file.  The `s//X&Y/` replaces what the `g//` found (the whole line) with `X`, what was found, and `Y`, except that the `X` is:

```
^[-_.]*
```

which means start of line followed by zero of more dashes, underscores or dots, and `Y` is:

```
[-@.]*
```

which means zero or more dashes, at signs, or dots.  If you need that anchored to the end of line, add a `$` after the `*`.

Note that the `-` must appear 'first' in a character class (unless another character must appear first, such as `^` to negate the character class, or `]` to match a close square bracket).

Comment: Is it really necessary to add `-` and `_` while there is a `.` (any character) matcher ? I think there isn't a need for a bracket expression in this case. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @limekin: inside a character class, `.` is just another character.  Most characters lose the special behaviour inside a character class, except `^`, `]` and `-` (and sometimes ``\`` too).  I suppose it would be more accurate to say `-` gains a special meaning inside a character class.

Comment: Strangely, a lot of lines in the file using > 'cat file | egrep -I -f whitelist | tee newfile' seemed to work until it got to the lower letters of the alphabet. Then, lines that did not match any name in my whitelist slipped through. Is there anything I can add to the whitelist to stop that?

Comment: Note that you have a case of UUoC (useless use of `cat`).  You would need to show an example as it is unlikely that `egrep` makes a mistake.